# adding link to suite bar in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-controls, elements-xml, delegate-control

I have followed the following liks to add custom links to sharepoint 2013 suite bar.

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/findnavish/sharepoint-2013-customizing-suite-bar)

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/11/04/adding-your-own-links-to-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/

Code executed and Farm level feature activated successfully. but I could not see my custom link in Suite Bar ?

any idea what is I am missing ?

Comment: try to increase Sequence attribute of delegate control.

Comment: John Chapman's blog is great for this. Especially in this case where you want to keep the original links: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-adding-links-suite-bar-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-overriding-suitelinksdelegate-delegate-control/

Answer (score 2):

I always have added custom links to the suite bar using a small jquery script on the page

On SharePoint 2013 you can do that using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var suiteBar = $("#suiteBar").find(".ms-core-brandingText");
suite.html("<a href="www.google.com"> custum link </a>");   
</script>
```

If you are using Office 365 you can use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var suiteBar = $("#suiteBrandingBox");
suite.html("<a href="www.google.com"> custum link </a>");   
</script>
```

Both codes here will change the sharepoint logo and add a custom link on it's place.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but not a very good solution. For example, to change the SharePoint logo permanently no more than two-three rows of Powershell is needed. This will improve performance on every page load

Comment: Robert you are right but for Office 365 you can't run the powershell

Comment: True, but the question is targeted for SharePoint Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy step no need to use powershell or visual studio follow these steps :

- Be sure that you have proper permission to edit share point
- Use share point designer to edit share point file
- go into master pages from left panel "INSIDE SHAREPOINT DESIGNER"
- right click on seattle.master then click on Edit file in Advance Mode
  "GET BACKUP IF YOU ARE NOT EXPERT IN SHAREPOINT DESIGNER"
- Find id="DeltaSuiteLinks" then paste below code exactly right after
  `<SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteLinks"

  BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks">` This Tag.

Code:

```
<span id="intranet" class="ms-core-suiteLink">
    <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" href="http://YOURLINKADDRESS">
      <asp:Label ID="intranet" runat="server" Text="Intranet"></asp:Label>
    </a>
</span>
```

Note : Remember If you Want to have more Links you should Copy and paste last 5 lines of code "Remember to change span id="intranet" and Label ID"Intranet" in each link"

Answer (score 1):

The following code it's a sample that can be used to add html (or even .js references) on the suite bar on a web app scope.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication [WebAppUrl]
$wa.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div class='ms-core-brandingText'>SharePoint (custom html)</div>"
$wa.Update()
```