# SharePoint 2016 - How to add custom link/button in SuiteBar

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, suitebar

I want to add custom link or button in suitebar in master pages -  oslo and seattle.

Here:

[image]

Comment: Please check if answer at this link is helpful.... https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/160590/38824

Comment: This is for sharepoint 2013. In 2016 DeltaSuiteLinks doesnt exist in master page html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooops my bad... For 2016 as you rightly said we don't have SuiteBarLinks in master page.

Ref link - [Edit Suite Bar Links in Sharepoint 2016](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194278/edit-suite-bar-links-in-sharepoint-2016)

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var customLi = "<li class='ms-core-suiteLink'><a class='ms-core-suiteLink-a' target='_blank' href='https://rootsite/SitePages/Home.aspx'>Home</a></li>";
if(jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").length > 0){
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").append(customLi);
       }
else {
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").html('<ul class="ms-core-suiteLinkList">' + customLi + '</ul>' )
}
</script>
```

Comment: This post is for sharepoint 2013. In sharepoint 2016 doesnt exist this ID->suiteLinksBox.

References to your js code: https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/customize-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/

Comment: Above answer is for 2016 only.